# Python: get OS version of server with kubernetes running (inside containers)

Tags: python, kubernetes, containers

im looking for the OS version(such as Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS) to get it from container that run on kuberentes server. i mean, i need to OS of the server which on that server i have kubernetes with number of pods(and containers).
i saw there is a library which call "kubernetes" but didn't found any relevant info on this specific subject.
is there a way to get this info with python?
many thanks for the help!

Comment: so basically you want the OS details of the host node on which the container is running ?

Comment: if that is the case, you may read `cat /proc/version` from within the container

Comment: @P....thanks for the answer.
 this command show me the same info from the server and from the container, is it take the info from the server host where kubernetes installed?

Comment: yes, it shows the info from the host node

Answer (score 3):

If you need to get an OS version of running container you should read

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/get-shell-running-container/

as it described above you can get access to your running pod by command:

kubectl exec --stdin --tty <pod_name> -- /bin/bash

then just type "cat /etc/os-release" and you will see the OS info which your pod running on. In most cases containers run on unix systems and you will find current pod OS.

You also can install python or anything else inside your pod. But I do not recommend to do it. Containers have minimum thing to make you app work. For checking it is ok, but after it just deploy new container.

Comment: i have a service which need to take the os of the server host.
i need to type a command from python service to take the os version info.
the command you gave me show the os info of the current instance and what i want is the os info of the server host from the container

Answer (score 2):

Using the node info on which pod is running via kubectl. In the below command, replace the `<PODNAME>` with your pod name.

```
kubectl get node $(kubectl get pod <PODNAME>  -o jsonpath='{.spec.nodeName}') -o jsonpath='{.status.nodeInfo.osImage}'
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, very helped me.
somehow when i enter the command of 'cat /proc/version' im getting the output but with 2 lines, one with the expected result and second line with 0. how can i filter that?
also, is there a way to filter only the UBUNTU-20.04 version with linux command?

Comment: can you show the output you are getting? @twome

Comment: alright, i fix that, it was python fault. now i have this output:


'Linux version 5.13.0-41-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-017) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #46~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 20 13:16:21 UTC 2022'

i want only the '20.04.1-Ubuntu' if that possible

Comment: to be honest, I realized that `/proc/versions` is not a true indicator of host OS. it's mainly for the host kernel version which is not the same as OS. So I removed that, I would advise querying the node to get the host OS version as described in the answer.

Comment: I have to query it from the container itself but it’s not possible with kubectl in the container. So there is no options to get is version info of the server from the container. Thanks anyway for the help.